# Add and remove pagination .active class when I click in next and prev arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I add this pagination.js script when you change page 1,2,3,4,5

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $listItems = $('.pagination li');

  $listItems.click(function(){
    $listItems.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');  

  });
});
```

I want add a function to prev and next arrow of carrousel, when your click on the arrow, the function remove class .active of the previous page and add the .class active in the next page.

Arrow controls code:

```
<div class="arrowPosition2"> 
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left arrowSlider"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right arrowSlider"></span>
              </a>
</div>
```

My english is not very good, you can see this screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

```
 <div class="arrowPosition2"> 
              <a id="arrowPrev" class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left arrowSlider"></span>
              </a>
              <a id="arrowNext" class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right arrowSlider"></span>
              </a>
 </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $listItems = $('.pagination li');
  var $arrowItems = $('.arrowPosition2 a');

  $listItems.click(function(){
    $listItems.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');  
    var activeLink=$(this);
  });

     $('#arrowPrev').on('click',function(){
    var $activeLi=$('.pagination').find("li.active");
    $activeLi.removeClass('active');

    if($activeLi.prev()!=null && $activeLi.prev()!=undefined ){
    $activeLi.prev().addClass('active');  
    }else{
    $('.pagination').find("li:last").addClass("active")
    }
    });

     $('#arrowNext').on('click',function(){
    var $activeLi=$('.pagination').find("li.active");
    $activeLi.removeClass('active');

    if($activeLi.next()!=null && $activeLi.next()!=undefined ){
    $activeLi.next().addClass('active');  
    }else{
    $('.pagination').find("li:last").addClass("active")
    }
    });


});
```

Comment: can u write your code in feddle  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call next and prev function of jquery jCarousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420728/call-next-and-prev-function-of-jquery-jcarousel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plz change if condition

```
if($activeLi.next().length>0 ){
$activeLi.next().addClass('active');  
}else{
$('.pagination').find("li:first").addClass("active")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you

```
var activeLink;

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $listItems = $('.pagination li');

  $listItems.click(function(){
  $listItems.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');  
  var activeLink=$(this);////  store in variable and do work on pev next btn
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks guy, I store the variable, but, ¿how do function works?, I´m beginner with javascript. I´m edited the main post with my arrows controls code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Arrow').on('click',function(){
var $activeLi=$('.pagination').find("li.active");
$activeLi.removeClass('active');

if($activeLi.prev()!=null && $activeLi.prev()!=undefined ){
$activeLi.prev()..addClass('active');  
}else{
$('.pagination').find("li:last").addClass("active")
}
});
```

Comment: change $('#Arrow') to $('.arrowPosition2')

Comment: Oh thanks, this works with the prevArrow, but I have a nextArrow too, ¿Use I the same function?

Comment: tell me all both arrows have same class or diff?

Comment: I´m edit the main post, this works now with next and prev arrow, I used a #arrowLeft and #arrowNext, I change your #arrowLeft function prev() by next(). But, when the .active class is in the last page, the .active class disappear.

Comment: check on next if($activeLi.next()!=null && $activeLi.next()!=undefined ){

Comment: where add this conditional sentence?, I´m have edited the main post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#NEXT_ARROW_ID').on('click',function(){
var $activeLi=$('.pagination').find("li.active");
$activeLi.removeClass('active');

if($activeLi.next()!=null && $activeLi.next()!=undefined ){
$activeLi.next().addClass('active');  
}else{
$('.pagination').find("li:first").addClass("active")
}
});
```

Comment: what happens at last?

Comment: You can try my code this: [link](http://ecoavantis.com/iucn/asignacionFondos.php?activa=index&idioma=es)

Comment: plz check i have just added new answer i think it will help you

Comment: i have tested in your link only u need to change if condition it works perfact

Answer (score 1):

this is your : pagination.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $listItems = $('.pagination li');
var $arrowItems = $('.arrowPosition2 a');

 $listItems.click(function(){
$listItems.removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');  
var activeLink=$(this);
});

 $('#arrowPrev').on('click',function(){
var $activeLi=$('.pagination').find("li.active");
$activeLi.removeClass('active');

if($activeLi.prev().length>0 ){
$activeLi.prev().addClass('active');  
}else{
$('.pagination').find("li:last").addClass("active")
}
});

$('#arrowNext').on('click',function(){
var $activeLi=$('.pagination').find("li.active");
$activeLi.removeClass('active');

if($activeLi.next().length>0){
$activeLi.next().addClass('active');  
 }else{
$('.pagination').find("li:first").addClass("active")
}
});


});
```